# How to change the content on ViewPager Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, navigation-drawer

I have a Navigation drawer that displays a list and a viewpager that displays content. When clicked on a particular item in list on navigation drawer a URL is generated for all pages and that url should result in change in content of the view pager. Navigation drawer and viewpager are in same Activity. The fragments in view pager have URLs that retrieve content from server. How can i acheive it?

Some of the code is below:

### Activity Class

```
public void View_pager() {

    viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    actionbar = getActionBar();

    adapter = new TabsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    viewpager.setAdapter(adapter);

    actionbar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    for (String tabs_name : tabs) {
        actionbar.addTab(actionbar.newTab().setText(tabs_name)
                .setTabListener(this));
    }

    viewpager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionbar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        }
    });
}
```

There are three pages in the viewpager. The adapter is below :

### Adapter

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

public TabsPagerAdapter(
        android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
    super(fragmentManager);

}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {

    switch (index) {
    case 0:
        return new Page1();
    case 1:
        return new Page2();
    case 2:
        return new Page3();
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 3;
}

}
```

The Pages have all a URL field that is used to extract json from server containing data. So in short, the question is how to change content in pages of viewpager when list item in Navigation drawer is clicked?

Comment: So when you tap on a navigation item you want to generate an URL to each of your fragments and pass that to each of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot reference each page fragment directly. So you could do:

1. If you have the same url or these urls are random and it doesn't matter which one goes where, generate them and send a broadcast message where you will put the URL in the broadcast intent. Each of your fragments are registering a broadcast receiver for that message type and when you have received the intent, get the URL and there you have it.
2. If the url is dependent for each fragment, generate the url from fragment. Just that you need to know when the user pressed on an item from navigation drawer. Again: when the user tapped on an item, broadcast a message (maybe including the option), each fragment will receive it and will know to generate the URL.

Makes sense?

Comment: Ok that makes sense. I'll try this approach.

Comment: Tried to implement it, didn't work.

       Intent intent = new Intent();
  intent.setAction("CONTENT_UPDATE");
  intent.putExtra("CATEGORY", mCategoryTitles[position]);
  getApplicationContext().sendBroadcast(intent);

Comment: What didn't work? Did you receive the broadcast in each fragment? Can you log it?